Running abp.io Blazor problem in the ConfigureServicesAsync
I am trying to run a Blazor webassembly multi-tiered using sql and entity framework
I have run the DBmigrator, added the libraries, and ran the Http.Api.Host solution.
when running blazor it is stuck on a white screen with the loading dot. in the console I have this message:

Error: One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred during
ConfigureServicesAsync phase of the module
SM.AMS.Blazor.AMSBlazorModule, SM.AMS.Blazor, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. See the inner exception for
details.)

What am I missing?
I am using abp 8.1.3

I have same error after upgrading 8.2.2

I encountered the same issue after upgrading from ABP 8.1.3 to 8.2.2, but I found the cause and resolved it.
Solution:
First, I added a try-catch block in the MyProjectBlazorModule.cs file to pinpoint the cause of the error. It turned out that the issue was related to the Blazorise Bootstrap files. I resolved it by updating the Blazorise Bootstrap NuGet packages from version 1.4.1 to 1.5.2, which eliminated the problem.
Pro Tip: After upgrading ABP, it's a good practice to run the "abp bundle" command in your Blazor project folder.
